# GSAP text shining animation on hover

Tags: reactjs, gsap

I am building a link component using react js and gsap for animation, what I want to do is when I hover I want the animation to start, and while hovering it should keep repeating but after I the mouse leave I want it to resume the animation first and then kill it so it shouldn't kill animation immediately.

```
const Link = forwardRef<HTMLAnchorElement, LinkProps>(
  ({ children, variant, ...props }, ref) => {
    const textRef = useRef<HTMLAnchorElement>(null);

    const tl = useRef<GSAPTimeline>();
 
    useEffect(() => {
      if (textRef.current) {
        const ourText = new SplitType(textRef.current, {
          tagName: "span",
          types: "words, chars",
          wordClass: "",
          charClass: "",
        });
 
        const chars = ourText.chars;
 
        tl.current = gsap.timeline({
          paused: true,
        });
 
        tl.current
          .to(chars, {
            opacity: 0.2,
            ease: "power2.inOut",
            stagger: {
              amount: 0.4,
              ease: "none",
            },
          })
          .to(
            chars,
            {
              opacity: 1,
              ease: "power2.inOut",
              stagger: {
                amount: 0.4,
                ease: "none",
              },
            },
            "<+=0.3"
          );
      }
    }, []);
 
    const handleMouseEnter = () => {
      tl.current?.restart().repeat(-1);
    };
 
    const handleMouseLeave = () => {
      if (tl.current) {
        tl.current.resume().kill();
      }
    };
 
    return (
      <a
        ref={textRef}
        onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
        onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
        className={cn(linkStyle({ variant }))}
        {...props}
      >
        {children}
      </a>
    );
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

so that you can use the `React.createRef()` method to a ccess the DOM element and pass it to a GSAP timeline.then you can add `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` event handlers to your component and use the `play()` and `pause()` methods of the timeline to control the animation as well.

Comment: yeah I am using ref there, but I don't want the animation to just pause immediately it should pause after the animation finishes